# How to spend two outputs of two different scripts

Tags: plutus

I've tried to implement a logic which can spend 2 outputs of 2 different scripts and create 2 new UTxOs:

```
lookups = Constraints.typedValidatorLookups instance1
          <> Constraints.otherScript script1
          <> Constraints.otherScript script2
          <> Constraints.unspentOutputs (Map.singleton txOutRef1 txOutTx1)
          <> Constraints.unspentOutputs (Map.singleton txOutRef2 txOutTx2)

tx = Constraints.mustPayToTheScript datum1 value1
          <> Constraints.mustSpendScriptOutput txOutRef1 redeemer
          <> Constraints.mustPayToOtherScript (validatorHash script2) (Datum $ PlutusTx.toData datum2) value2
          <> Constraints.mustSpendScriptOutput txOutRef2 redeemer

submitTxConstraintsWith lookups tx
```

But when I run the code, I'm faced with the error:

```
WalletError (ValidationError (ScriptFailure (EvaluationError [])))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you also share the validator function for both scripts? One of the scripts is not letting spend the output

Comment: I've implemented on-chain function yet. I've implement off-chain first and tested it, so just having a validator return True value. I make sure this issue doesn't come to the validator

Comment: If I return false in the validator, the error is validator error message. But when I return true, the error above is presented. It's reason why I think the above error doesn't come from OnChain validator

Comment: It definitely looks as if the error happens in validation. Please share the code of both validators you are using - including the types you're using for datum and redeemer for both.